# Git problems - not able to add my files to my repositories

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I'm trying to add my files from my index tree to git repository but they are not adding, throwing an error as follows

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
modified:   Roles/maven-standalone (modified content)
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I tried again and again, showing same thing !

Comment: What exactly did you try again and again?

Comment: Please show us commands you are using. I guess you want to use `git add` command

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git add .` command to add the files? Try this:

```
$ git status                  # see you changes
$ git add .                   # add the files
$ git commit -m 'Added'       # commit 
$ git push origin HEAD        # push to remote
```